# Проблема с JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Здесь код, где я вставляю в данные базу данных.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Здесь структура базы данных:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Ошибка unknown column in field list.Не знаю что делать

Comment: строки в кавычки поместите ...'vlad','moskovkin'...

Comment: Замените изображения текстом кода, DDL и ошибки.

Comment: Поставил минус за плохое оформление поста: исходный код стоит приводить текстом, а не скриншотами.

Answer (score 1):

Вы создаёте SQL запрос со всеми вносимыми данными простой конкатенацией текста, что делать крайне нежелательно. Это нехорошо, как с точки зрения скорости обработки, так и безопасности. Можете запросто получить SQL injection. Более того вы делаете это неправильно из-за чего получаете синтаксически неверный SQL.

1. Измените запрос на постоянный с параметрами, например такой:
   `INSERT INTO cards (password, sum, name, surname, number_of_cards) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`
2. Используйте `PreparedStatement` вместо просто `Statement` и заносите данные через соответствующие сетеры параметров с индексом, который начинается с единицы. Например: `ps.setString(1, "qwerty");` `ps.setString(2, 1234);` `ps.setString(3, "Иван");` и так далее, где `ps` - это экземляр `PreparedStatement`.

Answer (score 1):

Согласно синтаксису,который предлагает SQL все численные параметры указываются без кавычек:
INSERT INTO numbers(num1 , num2 , num3) VALUES(26 , 03 , 2001);
Остальные же типы - символьные и их подобие указываются в кавычках:
INSERT INTO user(surname , name) VALUES('Sckoriy' , 'Sergey');
В вашем случае int - численный тип,а char - символьный.